# Can polarization occur if both charges are neutral?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, polarization

If I keep neutral conductive pieces of some metal close to a neutral conductive sheet, what will happen? Will any of them get polarized or nothing will happen. 
My guess is nothing will happen as for polarization atleast one of the object should be charged.

Comment: Polarization doesn't imply a total charge not null ; it is a redistribution of the centers of positive and negative charges in the object.

Comment: If your particles are atoms or molecules, they will attract each other on account of fluctuations which produce a dipole moment in one, which induces a dipole moment in the other.  This is called the [London dispersion force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, the answer is "nothing will happen". However, if you bring the surfaces close enough together, you may find that electron affinity between the two is different, in which case electrons may move by a very small amount - in the same way that when atoms react, the resulting molecule may have a dipole moment. The effect would be restricted to the surface layer only - and therefore be tiny.